# Passing POST Variable in Ajax Request for Reload not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a button with the id `#filter`

```
<input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info" />
```

My Ajax script is as followed:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){  
 $('#filter').click(function(){  
            var rangestart = $('#rangestart').val();  
            var rangeend = $('#rangeend').val();  
            if(rangestart != '' && rangeend != '')  
            {  
                 $.ajax({  
                      method:"POST",  
                      data:{rangestart:rangestart, rangeend:rangeend},  
                      success:function(data)  
                      {  
                           window.location = 'http://www.test/daterange/dates.php?rangestart=' + rangestart +'&rangeend=' + rangeend
                      }  
                 });  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 alert("Please Select Date");  
            }  
       });  
  });
```

I click my `#filter` button, and it works as expected.

`rangestart` is passing the value of my input box (in the case below `04-15-2017`)
`rangeend` is passing the value of my input box (in the case below `04-20-2017`)

So the page reloads, and the url in the address bar is:

```
http://www.example.com/daterange/dates.php?rangestart=04-15-2017&rangeend=04-20-2017
```

In my `dates.php` file I have

```
$rangestart = $_POST['rangestart'];
$rangeend = $_POST['rangeend'];
```

at the top of the page. But even with the data passing in the address bar `$rangestart` and `$rangeend` are both empty and thusly cannot do anything with them as intended.

Anyone know what the issue may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.location` redirect is a GET request so you need to use `$_GET` not `$_POST` in dates.php

```
$rangestart = $_GET['rangestart'];
$rangeend = $_GET['rangeend'];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access them in the address bar use $_GET['rangestart'].

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  The `$.ajax({ method:"POST"`confused me.  `$_GET` is working great.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX method is used to load new info without page refresh. If you are reloading on the response then it's better if you pass the date via query string.

Coming to the error, I think PHP script not sending any response for that request. You can check the response in the NETWORK > XHR section of developer toolbar. Also, add error function to the ajax call to check errors as given below,

```
$.ajax({  
    method: "POST",  
    data: { rangestart: rangestart, rangeend: rangeend },  
    success:function(data) {  
        window.location = 'http://www.test/daterange/dates.php?rangestart=' + rangestart +'&rangeend=' + rangeend
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wait, where is he even sending the AJAX response?

Comment: to a window reload function

Comment: He is just reloading the page on the response. He needs to follow best practices.